# Changing delimiters for DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION in Google's Cloud Vision API

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-vision

I'm trying out Google's Cloud Vision API for text detection and have noticed the detection is using symbols such as `:`, `-` and `/` as breakpoints. I do not want them to be breakpoints in the scanned text as they make parsing the results for information more difficult. Looking through the documentation, the closest things I've found is `DetectedBreak()` from the `full_text_annotations`, which did not seem to have the utility that I need, and `TextDetectionParams()` which will be inserted into `ImageContext()` before being passed to the client as a request. For `TextDetectionParams()`, there is an option called `advanced_ocr_options`, but I have not been able to find any details on what options are available in it both in the library's documentation and Google's cloud vision api documentation found here: https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/vision/latest/google.cloud.vision_v1.types.TextDetectionParams

Is there any documentation for `advanced_ocr_options` or is there a better way to define breakpoints for the annotation request? The documentation in the link above does not go into any detail about what `advanced_ocr_options` actually entail, only that it is a `MutableSequence[str]`.

My existing code for additional context below:

```
feature = Feature(type_=Feature.Type(11)) # sets detection type to document_text
detection_params = vision.TextDetectionParams() # where advanced_ocr_options is an option in constructor
context = ImageContext(language_hints=["en"], text_detection_params=detection_params)

request = vision.AnnotateImageRequest(image=image, features=[feature], image_context=context)
reply = client.annotate_image(request)

#tried playing around with both text_annotations and full_text_annotations, unable to get the result I was looking for.
annotations = reply.text_annotations
full_annotations = reply.full_text_annotation
```

I know it is possible to take the full text returned by `text_annotations` and `full_text_annotations` and split it with `string.split()`, but as I do need to compare the tokens coordinate values I do not want to do this.

This is an example of what I got from the annotations (after formatting the coordinates) from the original text of `01/JAN/1990/`

```
01
bounds: (472,161),(537,162),(536,197),(471,196)
/
bounds: (553,163),(582,163),(581,197),(552,197)
JAN
bounds: (593,163),(703,165),(702,200),(592,198)
/
bounds: (716,166),(745,166),(744,200),(715,200)
1990
bounds: (759,166),(905,168),(904,203),(758,201)
/
bounds: (921,169),(948,169),(947,203),(920,203)
```

While I'm looking for something closer to

```
01/JAN/1990/
bounds: (472,161), (948,169), (947,203), (471,196)
```

If none of this is an option I intend to parse through the annotations individually and re-construct the items based on expected rules, but this could lead to additional errors especially if there is a mischaracterization by the OCR. The code used to format the bounds currently is as follows:

```
    #annotations[0] is the text dump with full spaces and symbols as a single string, but only coordinates of the bbox of the entire text
    for text in annotations[1:]:

        print(text.description)

        vertices = (['({},{})'.format(vertex.x, vertex.y)
                    for vertex in text.bounding_poly.vertices])
        print(vertices) #this is for currently for testing so im just using print to see what the outputs I collect are
```

Notably for the image example, I do not need the day (FRI) but can handle its inclusion separately.
[image: Cropped image for the date example]

Comment: Can you provide a sample image you are trying to read through google cloud vision?

Comment: Can't add it to the post currently due to the edit limit on SO, but as it may contain some information that shouldn't be disclosed are you okay with a cropped version containing just the date as per the example?

Comment: Can you share the articles you are following and the cropped image(only the date part)?

Comment: I wasn't following any particular articles, was mostly going off of testing the API with my own images and looking through the API documentation + stack overflow.

Comment: Based on my understanding we can’t specify `breakpoints`. So If you want this feature in cloud vision api, you can raise a feature request in [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests).

Comment: @kiranmathew thanks for the info, I'll do that but for now I'll use a workaround in my implementation.